# Safely uninstall ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: grub2, windows

I can't log into ubuntu anymore after an update, and would like to install linux light or Lubuntu instead. I read I could just delete the partition which I was about to do through windows 8's Disk managment, but also read it removes grub which I need to boot my PC. The problem is, I don't have a Windows recovory disk. I do have a recovery partition by default appearently. How can I remove Ubuntu without having to worry about this?

Answer (score 0):

> I read I could just delete the partition which I was about to do through windows 8's Disk managment,

Go ahead. Mind though it will remove anything from disk. In case you need to save something use the Ubuntu installation disk to save it. By the way: there is not need to remove it from Windows. You will be prompted to replace a current Ubuntu installation during the setup.

> but also read it removes grub which I need to boot my PC

No you do not. If there is just Windows on it you do not need it. Plus when removing your Ubuntu installation and installing a new version it will also install Grub.

> How can I remove Ubuntu without having to worry about this?

You assume there is something to worry about ;) Mind though: when messing with partitions make sure if there is anything important on that machine to make a backup even if you do not intend to mess with the partition that important stuff is on (like the Windows partition).

Comment: Thanks, I learned my lesson with backups the hard way. Since I'm dual booting, just delete ubuntu through Disk Manager and I'm good to go?

Comment: Yes. No guarantees on you messing up though ;-)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/614550/lubuntu-wont-start-without-a-random-cd-dvd-usb-inside I messed up horribly :I